# Can't access terminal menus from keyboard in 18.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, 18.04, gnome-terminal

After upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04,
The menu in Terminal does not open from the keyboard.

Holding the <kbd>ALT</kbd> underlines a letter in each menu header as normal, but pressing that key doesn't open its menu :-(

Pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> still opens the window menu, but the entries don't show any key shortcuts (no underlined letter). The only option seems to be pressing the <kbd>down arrow</kbd>  until the entry and then <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried <kbd>F10</kbd>? According to https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/KeyboardShortcuts it opens "Gear Menu", which seems to do the trick for me. I don't know what a gear menu is, though, so it might not work for you.

Comment: That's it, thank you. F10 then pressing the underlined letter works. So no more ALT key in Terminal (but ALT still works in other apps..)